# migrating application from zend framework (ZF)+ AngularJS to zend framework + Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, zend-framework, angular-fullstack, angular-migration

My application is in Zend framework + AngularJS. Where Zend framework gives us the routes and APIs for consuming in application.
current zend routes are like -
app.domain.com/home, app.domain.com/users

I am creating a new module let say it - app.domain.com/send-sms and want to develop it in Angular.

Now I am planning to migrate it AngularJS to Angular and everything else will be same this point of time.
Later all the modules will go in Angular (app.domain.com) and i will create api.domain.com (zend framework application for APIs)

Please suggest what will be the better approach to migrate modules gradually to shift completely on Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. You can use micro-frontend architecture: introduce a shell app (Angular) wrapping your old application as the first microfrontend(AngularJs) and finally introduce a 3d micro-frontend (Angular) which will contain your new features.
2. An alternative option is to use Angular elements. Such elements can be injected into your old application (AngularJs 1.7.x) helping you to stop expanding your tech-debt.
3. Use NgUpgrade to gradually migrate your app step by step (that's the most expensive solution but IMO it could be the best approach depending on your business needs / urgency )

web elements written in Angular and then